# A "Client - Server" performance issue

Tags: java, performance, client

I have a "Queuing Theory" problem where following are to be done:

- Develop a CLIENT to send continuous packets of fixed size to SERVER at fixed rate
- SERVER has to queue these packets and SORT them before handling these packets
- Then we need to prove (for some packet size 'n' bytes and rate 'r' MBps) the theoretical observation that **sorting**(n log n / CPU_FREQ) happens faster than **queuing** (n / r), and thus the QUEUE should not build up at all.

However, I find that Queue is always building up (running on two systems - client and server PCs/Laptops),

Note: When I run the processes on the same system, then Queue doesnt build and most of the time, it is down close to 1 - 20 packets.

Need someone to check/review my code.

**Code is pasted here:**

1. Client (Single Class):

   - Main: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=YEfQGXFZ
2. Server (Multiple Class files Package: **serverClasses**:

   - Main: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=BgZzfiTQ
   - Sorting: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=mPh8zgqC
   - ServerThreadPerClient: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=ZpTqpHnX
   - GlobalStatistics: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=Q2DJLvaV
3. Sample Graph for "QUEUE_LEN Vs. #PACKETS" for 10MBps and 10000 Byte sized packets for a duration of 30 - 35 secs

[image]

Comment: Some quick questions/observations: Is Arrays.sort using a fast enough sorting algorithm for your needs? Can a different sorting algorithm be used to get a faster sort for the type of data you're getting? Why are you manually invoking the GC in your sorting class?

Comment: It's really odd that the queue starts filling up when running client and server on mutually remote systems, yet gets emptied as fast as it fills up when client and server are on the same system. I'd expect the introduction of network latency to buy the server some time for sorting.

Comment: minor suggestion, but you should use `AtomicInteger` for the GlobalStatistics counters that you increment from multiple threads

Comment: @Freiheit I am not totally sure but guessing that JAVA would have implemented a good sorting algo(nlogn) for the purpose. The GC is to avoid JavaOutOfMemory error if running for long durations.

Comment: @G_H Yeah I too was expecting the same but going gaga :) over this unreasonable behavior. Any problem with the way I am locking the "GlobalStatistics" objects between the **Sorting** thread and Server's **clientThread**??

Comment: @mattb Yeah one option to be considered, but I am making sure that the increments are done in a 
<pre>synchronized</pre> block in **sorting** and **clientThread**.

Comment: Sorry, looks interesting, I am too lazy to investigate your code samples though. but the way I understand it, you can hardly prove anything as IO/transfer/receiving threads synchronization (do you even do non-blocking stuff) costs are magnitudes too high for anything that might show difference in too algorithms big O performance. Why not start with same machine, same JVM sample code and try building up understanding what is going on from there?

Comment: Hmm.. the actual requirement is as such! A separate CLIENT and SERVER are to be developed :(. So, cannot help myself.

Comment: And BTW as per http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char[]%29 Array.sort() uses a tuned quick sort ( O(n log n) ).

Comment: On the client it looks to me that the `timeinterval` is always going to be 0.  Was that the intension?  `timeinterval = 1 / (numpackets...)` and then you call `Thread.sleep(timeinterval)`.  At most this is going to sleep for 1ms unless I'm not reading the code right.  You say seconds but you never `*1000`.

Comment: Thanks @Gray!! Made this change. But how can we make sure it sleeps properly for `< 1msec` (i.e. when we pass 0.1 to `sleep()`)??

Comment: I've moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client it looks to me that the `timeinterval` is always going to be 0. Was that the intension?  You say seconds in the code but you are missing the `* 1000`.

```
timeInterval = 1 / ( noOfPacketsToBeSent );
```

And then you call `Thread.sleep((long) timeinterval)`.  Since `sleep()` takes `long` then this will at most sleep 1ms and usually (I suspect) sleep 0ms.  Sleep only has a millisecond resolution.  If you want nanoseconds resolution then you'll have to do something like:

```
   TimeUnit timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS;
   ...
   timeUnit.sleep(50);
```

I suspect that your CPU is limiting your runs when both the client and the server are on the same box.  When they are on different boxes then things back up because the client is in effect flooding the server because of the improper sleep times.

That's my best guess at least.

Comment: I think I am seeing the results now! Thanks a lot for your time on my code.